# How to store JSON type data in a MySql DB in Hibernate java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jackson, jax-rs

This is my field in domain class.

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "Field")
    public class Field implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
    
        @Type(type = "json")
        private String field;
    }
```

I am sending post request of this value using **postman** like this

```
"field":{"value":{"provider":"value","fields":{"label": "Field File", "type": "file", "required": true}}},
```

But when I am using this  `@Type(type = "json")` mySql db gives an error can't connect to the DB.

If use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`in class level with this way

```
@Type(type = "text")
private String field;
```

then this value `field` will pass as null and can't save the record in DB. How can i save this json data. I am using JAX -RX.

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Comment: I am using google sdk. cloud sql

Comment: @Shadow Google Cloud SDK 347.0.0

Comment: I need the exact mysql version. Your mysql instance may not support the json data type.

Comment: @Shadow My local Mysql worbench Server version is 5.7.34

Comment: My default target mySql version in modelling prefernces is 8.0.25